# Cannot deploy to Google App Engine due to bad import, not in my code

Tags: google-app-engine-go

I am trying to deploy an application to Google AppEngine using the beta deploy command: `gcloud beta app deploy app.yaml` and I have even tried to add: `--verbosity=info` to get more information.

Nevertheless I keep getting this error:

`Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "unsafe" in golang.org/x/sys/unix/dirent.go`

From what I can tell the error does not come from my code and the only external libraries I use is

- gorilla/mux
- sirupsen/logrus

Which from what I can tell also do not use any unsafe code. My local go version is `go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64` and I am using a standard environment on Google AppEngine.

Furthermore, locally the code runs as it should.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` package is using the `golang.org/x/sys/unix` package.

See: https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/search?q=unix&type=Code

You can't use on Google AppEngine standard any package that uses `unsafe` or imports other package that use it.

Comment: So I will have to use the build log, damn it. Thanks will test

Comment: I use https://github.com/strongo/app/tree/master/log for abstraction and https://github.com/strongo/bots-framework/blob/master/hosts/appengine/logger.go as implementation.